# how does chromium`s auto_play white_list work?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Chrome blocks `autoplay` attribute of "video" tag.

Here is the code in `chrome_content_browser_client.cc`:

```
bool IsAutoplayAllowedByPolicy(content::WebContents* contents,
                               PrefService* prefs) {
  DCHECK(prefs);

  // Check if we have globally allowed autoplay by policy.
  if (prefs->GetBoolean(prefs::kAutoplayAllowed) &&
      prefs->IsManagedPreference(prefs::kAutoplayAllowed)) {
    return true;
  }

  if (!contents)
    return false;

  // Check if the current URL matches a URL pattern on the whitelist.
  const base::ListValue* autoplay_whitelist =
      prefs->GetList(prefs::kAutoplayWhitelist);
  return autoplay_whitelist &&
         prefs->IsManagedPreference(prefs::kAutoplayWhitelist) &&
         IsURLWhitelisted(contents->GetURL(), autoplay_whitelist->GetList());
}
```

As we can see here, there is a white list of some sites.

I tried to find them from chromium source code, but failed.
How can I get this list?

Comment: What do you mean by Chrome stored theme? Do you want to know where Chrome retrieves the white list of those sites?

Comment: Yes,I just want to get the list

Comment: Isn't this the whitelist you have in your preferences? `chrome://settings/content/sound`

Comment: http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoplayWhitelist

Comment: @Kaiido,   is about this link:  [google`s blog](https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/) , _"Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where we see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound"_

Comment: Hi @Kaiido , I readed the link about `AutoplayWhitelist`, it told us how to add sites to the whitelist , but not the whitelist that chrome build in own

Comment: This policy is what your code is referring to. I wasn't able to retrieve it from my mac, so I can't tell for sure. But note that this blog's article (and all the newspapers quoting it) is the only mention of such an auto-generated whitelist. The FAQ paragraph of [this page](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/autoplay) even states that "Unfortunately, Chrome cannot provide any whitelist exceptions to the autoplay policy."

Comment: And actually what the blog post was talking about is `chrome://media-engagement/` which does have pre-seeded informations.